# iOS QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED freezes while interacting with UI (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

Excuse me, if it is a stupid question, but i'm just trying to understand GCD.

I tried to do a simple thing: UITableViewController with one UITableViewCell and UIProgressView on the cell. And this progressView should update every second.

In **cellForRowAtIndexPatch** I did this

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("onlyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OnlyTableViewCell
cell.runChanges()
return cell
```

In **runChanges** function I just create timer

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("doSomething"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And **doSomething** looks like this:

```
func doSomething() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue),0)) {

        if self.i >= 100 {
            self.timer!.invalidate()
            return
        }
        ++self.i
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.prgrs.progress = Float(self.i)/100.0
            print(self.i)
        }
    }
}
```

So I thought that it would work all the time, while I interact (maybe) with the UI. And it works quite good while I don't touch it. But when I interact with UI, for example, scroll UITableView and hold my finger(mouse in simulator) on the screen, it freezes.
I thought if now it is 22% and I will scroll it and hold my finger for 10 seconds it maybe should continue from about 32% but it shows 23%.

Sorry for my English and stupidness.

Images and source [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6yrlegynmgz7opb/AACHSfMGbQdVWVX2y1FzC-FUa?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with NSTimer, adding your timer to mainRunLoop should fix it.

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("doSomething"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Comment: Note that `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` already schedules the timer on a run loop.  If you are going to schedule it yourself you should use the regular `timerWithTimerInterval` initializer